# ReadDone2 error on my WebClient

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, webclient

my xamarin project was running well but now, whitout touching anything sometimes it closes with this error:

> **System.Net.WebException** Error getting response stream(ReadDone2):
>   ReceiveFailure

i think that the problem is is my function that get elements from a php file this is the function:

```
#region GET TABLE
    public List<List<string>> GetTable(string url, string nome_array, List<string> array_col)
    {

        string elemento_name = nome_array;

        int fine = array_col.Count;
        Console.WriteLine(fine);


        var multiDimensionalArr = new List<List<string>>(); // CREO LISTA MULTIDIMENSIONALE DI TIPO STRINGA CHE CONTERRA' LA TABELLA RISULTANTE


        WebClient client = new WebClient(); // INIZIALIZZO CLIENT WEB

        string value = client.DownloadString(url); //JSON IN STRINGA VALUE

        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(value); //DESERIALIZZO JSON


        int i = 0; //VARIABILI PER IL CONTEGGIO ELEMENTI
        int j = 0; //VARIABILI PER IL CONTEGGIO ELEMENTI

        foreach (var item in jObject[elemento_name])  //PER OGNI ELEMENTO ESISTENTE NELL'ARRAY
        {
            multiDimensionalArr.Add(new List<string>()); //CREO NUOVA RIGA NELL'ARRAY

            do
            {
                multiDimensionalArr[i].Add(Convert.ToString(jObject[elemento_name][i][array_col[j]])); // AGGIORNO ARRAY CON ELEMENTO CORRISPONDENDE
                j++;
            } while (j < fine);


            j = 0;
            i++;
        }

        return multiDimensionalArr;

    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: UP* please can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure what versions of Xamarin you are using, but there was an old bug about this error, but it should be fixed a while ago: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19673
Might also check this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15509/error-getting-response-stream-readdone2-receivefailure . Some said that using ModernHttpClient, https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/,  resolved the issue even before the fix was released.